# Project /user(group) : Should be able to modify everything on a project from, until the project is move to accepted status

Tags: odoo

Project /user(group) : Should be able to modify everything on a project from, until the project is moved to accepted status. Then he should only be able to modify the project lines.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define fields with this attribute 'states' like this:

```
'date_order': fields.date('Date', required=True, readonly=True, select=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'sent': [('readonly', False)]})
```

It means that date_order field will be in read only mode when state will be draft and sent. Same you can do at your end to achieve your need.